# Get Name and Value of only frontend attributes of a product

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap-api-v2, android

How to get all attribute of a product. I try to manage this line of  code from internet or some other sources where i can easily able to fetch Product name,image,price and description but I failed to fetch all product Frontend and FrontendLabel like color,brand etc.I am new to php.So any help would be appreciate.

```
<?php 
    // Get products in category
    require_once('../app/Mage.php');//Path to Magento umask(0);

    if(isset($_GET["categoryId"])){
      $categoryId=$_GET["categoryId"];
        $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.prashant.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
        $sessionId = $proxy->login('prash', 'prashant123@'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

        $products= $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId,$categoryId);


        $itemDetails=array();
        Mage::app(); 

      foreach ($products as $item) { 

        $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->product_id);
        $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
        $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
        $price2=0;
        $price2=$product2->getFinalPrice();
        if($price2==0){
        $price2=$product2->getPrice();
        }



        $desc=$product2->getDescription();
               if($desc==""){
                $desc="blank";
               }

                $attributes=$product2->getAttributes();
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
                        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                        $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product2);        
                        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product2);
                        echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";        
        }
    }



               $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
               if($baseImageUrl=="http://www.prashant.com/media/catalog/product/"){
                $baseImageUrl="http://www.prashant.com/customApi/icon.png";
               }

               //"desc"=>$desc,

               $statusp=$product2->getStatus();
        $statusen= Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;


        if($statusp==$statusen){
             $itemDetails[]=array(
          "productId"=>$item->product_id,
          "name"=>$product2->getName(),
          "price"=>$product2->getPrice(),
          "spprice"=>$price2,
          "desc"=>$desc,
          "attributes"=>$attributes,
          "imageurl"=>$baseImageUrl,
          );
        }


      }
      //return array of products
      //echo "<pre>";
      //print_r($itemDetails);
      //echo "</pre>";
      echo json_encode($itemDetails);
      exit();
    }else{
      echo "error";
      exit();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code seems to be fine,

I think there is some problem with your setting,

For fetching this way your attribute should display yes in view page.

Because I think This is the same kind of code you will get into `catalog/product/view/attribute.phtml` file

For this setting go to

`Catalog->Attribute->Manage Attribute-> click on Your Attribute->
Frontend Properties ->Visible on Product View Page on Front-end` set to `Yes`

In your code remove this `if` condition  and might be It work for you

```
 $attributes=$product2->getAttributes();
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    //if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) { remove if condi
                    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                    $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product2);        
                    $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product2);
                    echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";        
   // } end remove if condi
}
```

**May be this issue because of you have not set current store. please set current store and check add below code after Mage::app();**

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($your_store_id);
```

Comment: its already YES

Comment: try this code `$product2->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product2)`

Comment: again not working but when i write color in place of 'attribute_code' it shows black and i want it should fetch label name too.

Comment: @PrashantDas So the code you have written worked only on home page only , let me check detail and I will answer you later for this

Comment: @PrashantDas check my updated answer

Comment: again not working @Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: @PrashantDas please check this updated answer and if wont work for you then try my new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code that will work for you.

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_attributes');
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $product2;
    $_additional = $block->getAdditionalData();  
     foreach ($_additional as $_data): 

            echo $block->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])); 
            echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
     endforeach;
```